# How to simply convert MIPS instruction to 32bits hex number

Tags: hex, mips

I'm working with ASM/MIPS technology and I want to train myself to conversion.

I wanna convert MIPS instructions to a 32bits hexadecimal number.
For example, I want to change sub$t0,$zero,$t1 to a hexa number.

I've find a lot of solutions, but everything is different.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIPS sub instruction subtracts two registers and stores the result in a register.`sub $d,$s,$t` means `$d = $s - $t`

```
sub = function code 34 (see manual), 22 in hex, 100010 in bin (6 bits)
$t0 = 8 in decimal, 8 in hex, 01000 in bin (5 bits)
$zero = 0 in decimal, 0 in hex, 00000 in bin (5 bits)
$t1 = 9 in decimal, 9 in hex, 01001 in bin (5 bits)
```

So the machine code for your instruction is `01001 01000 00000 100010`

For R-format instructions, the opcode, or "operation code" is always zero. rs, rt, and rd correspond to the two source and one destination registers.

The source `sub$t0,$zero,$t1` therefore translates to `0x00094022` in hexadecimal notation.

**Explanation**

Every MIPS instruction is 32bits and translates to a 32bits number that can be written as machine code in hexadecimal format.

The instruction sub (subtract) has opcode 0x22. Therefore the rightmost digits has to be 22 (see above that they are).

sub is an instruction type R. This means the R instructions are used when all the data values used by the instruction are located in registers.

All R-type instructions have the following format:

```
OP rd, rs, rt
```

Where "OP" is the mnemonic for the particular instruction (in this case sub). rs, and rt are the source registers, and rd is the destination register. In this case, the sub instruction is used as:

```
sub $t0, $zero, $t1
```

In other words, your instruction means "subtract t1 from 0 and put the result in t0".

If you want to swap the values of two registers you can do it as follows:

```
.text
.globl  __start
__start:

sw      $t0, x
sw      $t1, y
lw      $t0, y
lw      $t1, x
.data
x:
.word   0x000000FF
y:
.word   0xABCDE080
```

If you want to put the content in $t0 also in $t1, you can use the `or` instruction:

```
lui  $t0, 0x0123
or   $t1, $zero, $t0
```

Comment: I've tried by myself and I have the same result.
But I passed by binary (10010100000000100010). 
Your explication was good, thanks you.

But I have an other question : if I want to exchange the registry of $t0 and $t1 ? Should I convert it again or it's useless ?

Comment: It's so complicated.
So what I should do ? xchg 8,9?

Comment: If you want to swap the contents of $t0 and $t1, you can use first `sw` (store word) to save the values from the registers to RAM, and then `lw` to load the value from RAM to the registers. It will take 4 instructions.

Comment: Like :
`sw $t0
sw $t1
xchg t$0,t$1
lw $t0,$t1 ? `

Comment: I updated the answer with a small program that swaps the values. You can please try it if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah, your explications are very good. It works.
However, I have an other question.
The previous code is for 2 registers.
But if its for 1 memory content and one register ? (and 2 memory content pointed)

Comment: IIUC, you can do it with load word and store word. Just be careful that you know what you're doing, read the manual and test the code. But I'm not 100 % certain that I understand your new latest question. Maybe you can elaborate what you mean or ask a new complete question. Do you have 1 register, 1 memory location and you just want to replace the contents of the register with the new memory location? In that case you can do it with load word (I think).

Comment: Yeah, I have a $t0 memory pointed content and $t1 register.
I want to put the register on $t0 and the memory on $t1.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change which register is which, if that is what you want do to. $t0 is always register 8 and $t1 is always register 9. If you just need to copy from one register to another then you can use `or`  i.e. `or $t1, $zero, $t0` which will place the contents of register $t0 in register $t1 and leave $t0 unchanged. But maybe this is not exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: $t0 is a register
$t1 with memory pointed
I want to put the $t1 memory pointed on $t0 and the content of $t0 in $t1

Comment: I updated the answer with instructions how to put the content of $t0 in $t1. I'm not sure what is meant by "memory pointed", maybe we can clarify more what you need? And if you can look if the new code does what you need with copying between registers.

Comment: So my English is bad, that's why my explications are bad.
I will try again.
I want MIPS codes to swap : 
- two registers $t0 and $t1 (done before);
- memory content point by $t0 and register $t1,
- memory content point by $t0 and $t1

Comment: How about this instruction `lw $t1, 0($t0)` that will load $t1 with the address where $t0 points. I hope this is right for you.